# Build error: NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/XPathAPI

Tags: java, xpath, ant, teamcity

I have upgraded my J2EE web application from jdk6,tomcat6 to jdk7 and tomcat7
but while deploying teamcity is giving following error.

[xmltask] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/XPathAPI

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/XPathAPI
                at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.jdk14.XPathAnalyser14.analyse(XPathAnalyser14.java:29)
                at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.XmlReplace.apply(XmlReplace.java:72)
                at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.XmlReplacement.apply(XmlReplacement.java:61)
                at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask.processDoc(XmlTask.java:707)
                at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask.execute(XmlTask.java:676)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:37)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:382)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:668)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:187)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:246)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xpath.XPathAPI
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
                ... 25 more
```

Comment: XPathAPI isn't in your classpath

Comment: sorry but what does xpathAPI is? plz tell me so that i can add it

Comment: @mark o'connor this is not duplicate(i already added xalan-2.7.1.jar but issue not resolved)

Comment: Clearly it's not in the classpath. Xalan contains this class, see: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22org.apache.xpath.XPathAPI%22%20AND%20v%3A%222.7.1%22

Answer (score 4):

The missing class is contained in xalan-2.7.0 (See [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3a%22org.apache.xpath.XPathAPI%22%20AND%20v%3a%222.7.0%22)). So I think the problem is how your classpath has been set.

Considering that this appears to be an error reported by the [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) task, does this mean the error is being thrown by ANT?

Google found the following example which might be the answer to your problems:

- https://wiki.nci.nih.gov/display/NBIA/Migration+to+Java+7

Add the xalan jar to the classpath of your taskdef:

```
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement path="${common.lib.dir}/xmltask-1.15.1.jar" />
    <pathelement path="${common.lib.dir}/xalan-2.7.1.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Comment: I already have these entries in classpath, wondering what is wrong here

Answer (score 3):

if using maven add this to your dependencies section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but, i guess jar named xalan-2.4.0.jar is missing
please download it and place inside.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxalan240jar.htm

Comment: It already have xalan-2.7.0.jar

Comment: i think version matters

Comment: I agree but here I don't think so(with all due respect)

Answer (score 0):

Add xpath to your classpath and try the deploy again. If you are not sure which xpath jar you need search in the tomcat libraries folder for xpathapi jar

Xpathapi is a jar used for evaluating xpaths (related to xml) in java. if you are not sure which version you need, google for it and fetch the latest xpath api jar .

Comment: I tried this option but it not helping me.

Answer (score 0):

For now I just remove 

from my build.xml, and its working.
I know its not a solution but we have to deliver.

Answer (score 0):

In Build.xml, change the java version to 1.7 and classpath XMLTask from 1.15.1 to 1.16.1.. It works

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this, inlcuding **Xalan** and **Serializer**

1. Download [xalan-j2-2.7.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/xalan/xalan-j2-2.7.0.jar.zip) & [serializer-2.7.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadserializer270jar.htm)
2. Update build.xml to include these jars in path

   ```
   <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask">
       <classpath>
           <pathelement location="../xmltask-v1.14.jar"/>
           <pathelement path="../xalan-j2-2.7.0.jar"/>
           <pathelement path="../serializer-2.7.0.jar"/>
       </classpath>
   </taskdef>
   ```

This should get it running.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `import org.apache.xpath.operations.String;`.